# Add a website to IIS on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis

I was trying to add my ASP.NET website in IIS 7.5 on my local computer. I followed these steps in IIS Manager.

- Right-click sites>Add website and specify the physical path. (I chose the app pool as Default app pool)
- Right-click on the WebSite just added>Manage>Browse.

On trying to browse the website, I am getting this error

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Here's the screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7BPj.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the process your IIS App Pool is running under does not have read access to the directory you specified.

The IIS App Pool is probably running under Network Service or ASP .NET 4.0 account depending on the version of .NET you're using.

Try navigating to the physical directory and changing the security properties to give Network Service and ASP .NET 4.0 (if it exists on your computer) Read access.

Comment: Yes, the error code in the screenshot is 0x80070005 = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. It's usually the group IIS_WPG you want to give permissions to.

Comment: Here's my Web.Config http://pastebin.com/1SHH6KtM . Is something wrong in this? I am developing website for .NET 3.5 on VS2010 :-/

Comment: Could you please elaborate which security setting to modify and how?

Comment: I performed the steps mentioned here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055 for the Web.Config file in the physical path of my webiste but the same error still exists

Comment: D'oh, I meant IIS_IUSRS not IIS_WPG. To confirm, you've run resolution 2 method 2 from that link for the full path of your site, not just the web.config file? That ought to fix it, or at least give you a different error.

Comment: Yeah! Gave a different error then. Atleast I knew about what to do with that! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Have a run through this page

http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In the new website window under "Location" click on "Browse" to see the different Server options including *IIS Server*. User can select the server as IIS server instead of "File System", then the "Location" option will be "HTTP" instead of "File System".

- New Website
- Under Locations Click on "Browse"
- Click on "Local IIS" and then select the "IIS Virtual Directory"(IIS vitual Directory which is directory created by the user while configuring IIS server)
- Open